# There is an error in XML document (6, 14)

Tags: c#, xml

При попытке прочитать содержимое файла, выдает ошибку: "There is an error in XML document (6, 14)."

```
public struct Aeroflot
{
    public string Destination;
    public string Number;
    public string PlaneModel;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format($"{Destination} {Number} {PlaneModel}");
    }

    public void Vvid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input destination");
        Destination = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Input flight number");
        Number = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Input plane model");
        PlaneModel = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void GetValues(Aeroflot[] Flights)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS; i++)
        {
            Aeroflot flight = new Aeroflot();

            Console.Write("Input destination: ");
            flight.Destination = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Input flight number: ");
            flight.Number = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Input plane model: ");
            flight.PlaneModel = Console.ReadLine();

            Flights[i] = flight;

        }
    }
    const int NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS = 2;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Aeroflot[] Flights = new Aeroflot[NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS];

            //GetValues(Flights);
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS; i++)
            {
                Flights[i].Vvid();
            }

            XmlSerializer xmlSerialaizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Aeroflot));

            using (FileStream fw = new FileStream("output.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    xmlSerialaizer.Serialize(fw, Flights[i]);
            }

            
            Aeroflot[] bludaToRead = new Aeroflot[NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS];

            using (FileStream fr = new FileStream("output.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS; i++)

                    bludaToRead[i] = (Aeroflot)xmlSerialaizer.Deserialize(fr);
            }

            int matches = 0;
            string DestinationToCompare = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < Flights.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Flights[i].Destination == DestinationToCompare)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Flights[i].Number + " " + Flights[i].PlaneModel + " " + Flights[i].Destination);
                    matches++;
                }
            }

            if (matches == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is no matches");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы сериализуете два раза подряд в один XML файл?

Comment: Вы имеете веду, что я сереализую через цыкл, где пройсходит 2 итерации?
Если да, то тогда выдает ошибку: "There was an error generating the XML document."

Comment: конечно в файле ошибка. Версия `xml` должна указывается только раз и схема, вроде, тоже

Comment: можете проверить валидность с помощью сайта https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: Просто напишите `xmlSerialaizer.Serialize(fw, Flights);` и все, вам не нужен там цикл, ибо у вас получается в одном файле куча xml разом.

Comment: Немного исправил, теперь ошибки не выдает, но мне нужна как нибуть прочитать содержимое

Comment: `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Aeroflot[]))` - (де)сериализуйте массив целиком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public struct Aeroflot
{
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string PlaneModel { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format($"Destination: {Destination}. Number: {Number}. Plane model: {PlaneModel}");
    }
}
class Program
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS = 3;

    static void GetValues(Aeroflot[] Flights)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS; i++)
        {
            Aeroflot flight = new Aeroflot();

            Console.Write("\n Input destination: ");
            flight.Destination = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(" Input flight number: ");
            flight.Number = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(" Input plane model: ");
            flight.PlaneModel = Console.ReadLine();
            Flights[i] = flight;
        }
    }
    public static void Line()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Aeroflot[] Flights = new Aeroflot[NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS];

            Line();
            Console.WriteLine(" INPUT THE DATA:");

            GetValues(Flights);

                            
            List<Aeroflot> list = new List<Aeroflot>();

            list.AddRange(Flights);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerialaizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Aeroflot>));

            string pathXml = "file2.xml";
            using (FileStream fw = new FileStream(pathXml, FileMode.Create))
            {
                xmlSerialaizer.Serialize(fw, list);
            }
            Line();

            Console.WriteLine(" READ FILE .xml:\n");
            List<Aeroflot> bludaToRead = new List<Aeroflot>();

            using (FileStream fr = new FileStream(pathXml, FileMode.Open))
            {
                bludaToRead = (List<Aeroflot>)xmlSerialaizer.Deserialize(fr);
                foreach (Aeroflot i in bludaToRead)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($" Destination: {i.Destination}. Number: {i.Number}. Plane model: {i.PlaneModel}");
                }
            }
            
            Line();
            Console.Write("\n Input destination: ");

            string DestinationToCompare = Console.ReadLine();
            int matches = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Flights.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Flights[i].Destination == DestinationToCompare)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($" Number: {Flights[i].Number}\n Plane Model: {Flights[i].PlaneModel}");
                    matches++;
                }
            }
            if (matches == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n THERE IS NO MATCHES!!");
            }
            Line();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
 }
```